# Facebook SDK for Android in ubuntu

Tags: android, facebook, ubuntu, sdk

The tutorial for getting started with facebook apps with android has the instructions to install the SDK for Windows and for OSx but not for any linux distribution, I use ubuntu, and already downloaded the SDK but I don't know how to install it

Comment: Which instructions are you looking at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions posted [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/) seem to be pretty straightforward. The only part that talks about osx and windows is manually installing the apk on your device, but this only applies if you are trying to use it with an emulator. If you're testing on a real device, then you can ignore this step and simply download the facebook app from the Google play store. If you are using an emulator, then following the part for "osx" should work the same on ubuntu since osx is similar in many ways to linux systems.

As far as the rest of the instructions go, they are all using eclipse which should be independent of the os.